# xsl:param used without being assigned a value

Tags: xslt, parameters

I am looking at this xslt template:

```
  <xsl:template match="row">
    <xsl:param name="spans"/>
    <xsl:param name="browserows"/>

    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="contains($spans, '0')">
        <xsl:call-template name="normal-row">
          <xsl:with-param name="spans" select="$spans"/>
          <xsl:with-param name="browserows" select="$browserows"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
```

I am trying to understand where the value of $spans is coming from at the test statement on line 6, but it looks like the value was never assigned.
I cannot find spans as a global param anywhere.
Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would come from the calling code that executed the `<xsl:apply-templates>` that matched against that `row` - because the `<xsl:template>` declares that parameter in `<xsl:param name="spans"/>`. If you didn't specify a value via `<xsl:with-param>`, then it is presumably nil.

Comment: Thanks!! I was stuck with the notion that a template without a name or mode cannot be applied or called ...

Comment: @YakirGreen it isn't common, but indeed you can put `<xsl:with-param>` inside `<xsl:apply-templates>`. Perhaps the confusion is that `<xsl:apply-templates>` is usually self-closed, so you don't think about what could go inside.

Comment: What I was missing is that you can use <xsl:apply-template> without a name or a mode, just a select. Thanks!

Comment: Not "nil" - there is no such thing in the XSLT data model. Generally it will be an empty string or an empty sequence depending on which version of XSLT and whether or not there is an "as" attribute to define the type.